# scipy.optimize.curve_fit doesn't work when function to fit has only one argument

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a sine+cosine curve to my data with the amplitude only as a parameter and it seems like curve_fit can't work with a function that only has one parameter...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as scio

def function(x,a):
    y = a*np.sin(np.radians(x))
    return y

x = np.array(range(360))
y = function(x,3)
yn = y +0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(x))
popt,pcov = scio.curve_fit(function,x,yn)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/mj/Documents/NACO/VLT/DataReduction/<ipython-input-62-388a2d20a0c8> in <module>()
----> 1 popt,pcov = scio.curve_fit(function,x,yn)

 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, **kw)
     416 
     417    if (len(ydata) > len(p0)) and pcov is not None:
 --> 418        s_sq = (func(popt, *args)**2).sum()/(len(ydata)-len(p0))
    419        pcov = pcov * s_sq
    420    else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function)
    319 
    320 def _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function):
--> 321     return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
    322 
    323 def _weighted_general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function, weights):

TypeError: function() argument after * must be a sequence, not numpy.float64
```

Why is this such an issue for curve_fit?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!
MJO

Comment: FWIW, your code runs unmodified for me using `numpy 1.7.1`, `scipy 0.11.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It turns out that my versions of both numpy and scipy were extremely old...it works perfectly now :).Thanks!